# Flex child element is growing out of its parent defined size

Tags: html, css

**Context:** I want to update the CSS of a modal in my project, I can't touch the modal div CSS which define the height / width / position of the modal on the page. But I can update the style of everything inside.

I trIED to use flexbox but for a specific modal I have a form with a very long content. I want to display the submit button at the bottom of the modal, so the form is scrollable and the modal is not. But **my form is overflowing from the modal**.

As you can see in the `snippet` below, I have in pink the `div` representing my `modal` and in blue the `div` representing my `form`.
**How can I avoid this overflow and keep my buttons at the bottom of the modal ?**

```css
/* -- Cant change this -- */
#parent {
    width: 80em;
    height: 15em;
    background-color: lightpink;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50px;
    top: 82px;
    position: absolute;
}
/* -- Cant change this -- */

#preference {
    display: flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 5em;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}

.inter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form {
    background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="preference">

        <div>
            <h3>
                Modal title
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <ul class="menu">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="inter">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row actions">
                        <button>Cancel</button>
                        <button>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why cant you change #preference, you have 3 different display there...

Comment: I just can't change the #parent property, it's style is set at runtime by a js script

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply a overflow effect, the container should have a max-height. In this example I've set the `max-height` on the `.form` & this gives the desired effect.

```css
/* -- Cant change this -- */
#parent {
    width: 80em;
    height: 15em;
    background-color: lightpink;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50px;
    top: 82px;
    position: absolute;
}
/* -- Cant change this -- */

#preference {
    display: flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 5em;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}

.inter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form {
    background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 10em
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="preference">

        <div>
            <h3>
                Modal title
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <ul class="menu">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="inter">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                        <div>This is a long content</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row actions">
                        <button>Cancel</button>
                        <button>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ? The height of my modal is set as runtime by a js script, so I don't have this information when I want to style the form

Comment: Would agree, that overflow-y: scroll on the parent container would be a viable solution.
If you can't add it on the #preference, then create a wrapper div inside it with width: 100%; height: 100%; and overflow-y: scroll that.